# Rust is installed but it's not (where it claims to be)

Tags: rust, installation

I wanted to get started on Rust and so I went through the getting started guide on the Rust website. After running rustup-init for Widows Rust doesn't seem to be installed anywhere. I'd love to check if the PATH is working but the files dont't exist despite Rust claiming to be installed.

After installing all the necessary tools including the C++ build tools, I type rustc into the cmd and it says it isn’t recognised. Neither is anything else (cargo, or rustup). I thought it had something to do with the path variable not being assigned so I ran the rust-init installer again and it claimed to be located in Users/name/.cargo (which doesn’t exist). I also did a full search of my pc files and couldn’t find a .cargo folder. So I thought about reinstalling rust but to do that I need to do:

```
rustup self uninstall
```

I hope this isn't a common problem and that I've done a repeat question but I haven't managed to find this problem anywhere else and I don't even know how to proberly name this question...

Comment: Did you enable display of hidden files & folders since `.cargo` will usually be hidden.

Comment: Hidden items are shown in my file explorer

Comment: Check `DISK:\Users\USER\.cargo` directory

Comment: I have already tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um... so it just works now after restarting my pc regularly throughout the day. I litterally don't know why this happened and I'm sorry for the classic lame "It just works now"

Comment: This answer might have been more suitable as a comment.